# Objective-c NSPredicate - Filter by ObjectId across different NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, filter, nspredicate, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using the code below with my `NSFetchedResultController`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.objRelationship.ObjectId == %@", objectFromOtherContext.ObjectId];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

The `NSManagedObjectContext` being use by `NSFetchedResultController` is different from the `NSManagedObjectContext` of *objectFromOtherContext* variable. The `NSFetchedResultController` does not return any data. However, it is returning something if they are using the same `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Is there a way to filter by `ObjectId` if the `NSManagedObjectContext` of the `NSFetchedResultController` is different from the `NSManagedObjectContext` of the `NSManagedObject` that was passed to the predicate? (assuming the object is already saved on the persistent store).

Comment: Is this your actual code ? It should be `objectID`, not `ObjectId`.

Comment: No, I just typed it but the actual code is similar to it except for the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem today. You cannot use an object in a predicate that was created in a different context, you can't even use it's objectID. You'll need to query for the object first in the same context you want to search. Alternatively you could try doing [newContext objectWithID:objectFromOtherContext.ObjectId] and then using that in your predicate.